# Some explanation of the behavior of the fork system call?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork

I'm studying for the operating system exam and now I'm seeing a code for the behavior of the fork() system call.The main goal is to draw the tree of processes made by this code.I did it but I can't explain because when I run this code,it prints 6 times glob's values two of which different while all other equal.Why does it?It should not print a single value of glob(Precisely the value 2 of the variable glob)?Thanks to everyone!

this is the code:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

int glob=5;
int pid=0;

pid=fork();
glob--;
pid=fork();
glob--;

if (pid!=0) {
    pid=fork();
    glob--; } 

printf("Value=%d\n",glob);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried tracing execution using a pencil on paper and keeping track of the values that way?

Comment: Is "`glob`" just a meta variable name, like `foo`? It's not very well chosen, since it shadows a [POSIX standard function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) which can be confusing. This is not a problem you're seeing, but it's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with process 1.

The first call to `fork` creates a new process - 2.

Now, 1 and 2 keep running. Both call `fork` again, you have now created process 3 and 4.

Now you check if the returned pid is 0. If it isn't (which it won't be in process 1 and 2), you call `fork` again in process 1 and 2 and create process 5 and 6.

Processes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 now call `printf`.

Comment: On my sheet so I created the graph.Starts with process A that have GLOB=5.A fork in B and for B now GLOB=5.After "glob--" for A and B now glob is 4.Now A and B now forks in C and D respectively and for C and D glob is 4.After "glob--" GLOB is 3 for all the processes.Now starts the IF construct.This regards only the processes' father,therefore A and B processes.In this statement A and B forks creating respectively the process E and F and then decreasing the GLOB variable to 2.Now all the process prints the Glob value.For A and B the value is 2 while for the other 3.It's right?

Comment: @user5508485 glob is 2 for processes A B E F and for C D is 3

Comment: Why this?The fork system call in the If statement is called before of "glob--" therefore the processes E and F should be GLOB = 3.

Comment: @user5508485 because E and F inherit glob from parent process when its 3. Then they also continue from where they were created and decrease glob.

Comment: @TonyTannous So "glob--" in the IF statement regards also the processes child E and F created to the previous step?

Comment: @user5508485, yes, E and F are created in the if statement. And they will run `glob--`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating a three duplicate processes, Then original and duplicate processes operations are happening at the same time, some operations take longer than others.

Answer (score 0):

After first call to `fork()` you have two processes with variable `glob` decremented to `4`.

After second call to `fork()` you have four processes with variable `glob` decremented to `3`.

But then, only the ones that were parents in the second call (they received `!= 0` from the second call to `fork()`, these are two processes in total) do a third call to `fork()` (becoming four processes) and decrement the variable `glob` again to `2`---this is, the parents and the children, a total of four processes of a total of six)

so only four processes from the total of six, do the third decrement of `glob` and so, you expect four `2` values and two more with `3`.